# show desktop version of website if button is submited

Tags: php, mobile

Hello i can't solve my problem. When users is on mobile device and click on "show mobile version" or something like that it will show him desktop version of web and if he click again switch back it will switch to normal mobile.

Main problem is i dont know how my website can remember which version he want to see and keep it

Comment: If you use media queries you won't need to give the user a choice, they will see the same code optimised for their viewport.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your theme to a mobile-ready theme if a mobile device is detected (you can now enable/disable iPad/tablets).Manual Switcher - to allow your user to manually switch between desktop and mobile versions. Available in 3 versions: widget, option to automatically insert into footer, or template tag.Template functions to help determine which tier of mobile device (touch/smartphone/other) is viewing your site, to allow conditional content inclusion.Adds device and tier specific CSS selectors to the body_class, to allow conditional CSS (e.g. so in the same way you have ".single" that you can target ".iphone" or ".mobile-tier-touch".)

For refrence please have a look: [Wordpress Smart Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mobile-smart/)